# Automatically change ediff-diff-options based on buffer mode of targets

Tags: python, ediff, makefile-mode

I use ediff all the time and have ediff-diff-options set to -wBb. This works most of the time but I've gotten burned diff-ing some Python scripts and the occasional makefile since whitespace matters there. Anyone have some code that would automatically change ediff-diff-options based on the buffer mode? Ediff is quite large/complex and a bit beyond my elisp abilities.